# criteria for choosing a window for filter design?

Tags: filters, filter-design

When choosing any of windows(Bartlett, Rectangular, Hamming etc) for filter design, one important specification of window is minimum stop band attenuation

What can be other window specification(s) that are also required for making a choice?

For example I have been given specification of filter with stop band attenuation 21db, why should i choose only rectangular window? Why I can't choose Bartlett or Hamming window?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would one use a Hann or Bartlett window?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40598/why-would-one-use-a-hann-or-bartlett-window)

Comment: also: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14067/what-is-a-window-function-in-dsp-and-why-do-we-need-it

Comment: also: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9228/how-were-windows-originally-conceived

Comment: when you search for `[filter-design] [window]` or `[filter-design] [window-function]` you can find a wealth of information that will help you narrow down your question through research.